# Transverse momentum in the parton model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, standard-model, protons, partons

Why is it so important that the partons in the parton model have low transverse momenta? And transverse to what anyway? I mean, basically one looks to justify breaking the hadronic subgraph in hadron-lepton scattering into a partonic graph with an on-shell parton as an in-state and multiply that with the convolution over the parton density, right? How does that have anything to do with the components of the partons' momenta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parton model we assume that the parton has a momentum $\hat{p}=\xi P$, where $P$ is the proton momentum and $\xi\in[0,1]$. Thus, $\hat{p},P$ are collinear and therefore $p_T:=\hat{p}-(\hat{p}P)P=0$.